# Remove/hide class properties at compiletime based on value from a.config file

Tags: c#

In a class I want to remove/hide some properties at compile time based on a bool value in a static appsettings class that gets its values from a .config file.

It seems like I need to create an custom attribute and then decorate the class properties that I want to remove/hide with this attribute?

I'm looking for help creating such an attribute.

Comment: I believe you'll looking for [`#if`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Comment: I have been looking at #if, but because the value comes from another class: if(@AppConstants.GetSettings().ShowExtraProperties == true) I'dont think it will work?

Comment: Nope it won't. You need to know the value at compile time. Maybe you could read it at compile time from the MSBuild script though.

Comment: Any example of how to do this?